# Avoiding nested loop in this example

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a facebook-style messaging system, where two or more users can have a conversation. In this messaging system, a user should be able to leave the conversation, without deleting it for the other participants.

In order to do this, i have made a set of tables like so:

```
User-table
+---------+----------+
| user_id | username |
+---------+----------+
|       1 | john     |
|       2 | marc     |
|       3 | vince    |
+---------+----------+

Conversation-table
+-----------------+-------------------+---------------+
| conversation_id | newest_message_id | message_count |
+-----------------+-------------------+---------------+
|               1 |                 7 |             7 |
|               2 |                13 |             6 |
|               3 |                56 |            43 |
+-----------------+-------------------+---------------+

Message-table
+------------+---------+---------------------------------+
| message_id | user_id |             message             |
+------------+---------+---------------------------------+
|          1 |       3 | "Yea, i really like him a lot." |
|          2 |       5 | "Let's meet up later!"          |
|          3 |      13 | "Wow, thanks!"                  |
+------------+---------+---------------------------------+

Conversation_users-table
+----+-----------------+---------+
| id | conversation_id | user_id |
+----+-----------------+---------+
|  1 |               1 |       3 |
|  2 |               1 |       1 |
|  3 |               1 |       2 |
|  4 |               2 |       5 |
|  5 |               3 |      13 |
+----+-----------------+---------+
```

In my interface, i wish to display all the conversations in which a user is currently participating, along with the usernames of the other participants.

In order to do this i would have to get all the conversation-id's from the conversation_user-table in which the user is participating, and then go through the table again to get the user-id's of all the other participants of these conversations.

It works fine with a subquery like this:

```
SELECT user_id, conversation_id FROM conversation_users WHERE conversation_id IN (SELECT conversation_id FROM conversation_users WHERE user_id = 1)
```

but i am afraid that the nested query would decrease performance considerably.

Is there a better way to do this query?

Regards

Comment: Are your sure about your query? both tables are the same. Your query and: 
`SELECT user_id, conversation_id FROM conversation_users WHERE  user_id = 1` are the same

Comment: Yes - that is my intention. I have both conversation_id and user_id in the same table. I have one user_id, and need both conversation_id and all other user_id's that are participating in that conversation.